# Java Method isn't resolved by stack object

Tags: java, data-structures, methods, compiler-errors, stack

I was trying to solve a problem named push at bottom of stack.
I got the recursion logic but the thing is, I have written a method `pushAtbottom` but the method is not recognized by the `main` method and I don't understand why. The error is 'Can not resolve pushAtbottom'

```java
import java.util.Stack;

public class pushatbottom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stack<Integer> s =new Stack<>();

        s.push(1);
        s.push(2);
        s.push(3);
        s.push(4);
        s.push(5);
        s.pushAtbottom(6,s);
        while(!s.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println(s.peek());
            s.pop();
        }
    }

    void pushAtbottom(int data,Stack<Integer> s)
    {
        if(s.isEmpty())
        {
            s.push(data);
        }
        int top=s.pop();
        pushAtbottom(4,s);
        s.push(top);

    }
}
```

Comment: `pushAtbottom` is not a method of the `java.util.Stack` class, it's defined in your `pushatbottom` class. Use `pushAtbottom(6,s);`, not `s.pushAtbottom(6,s);`, also make that method `static`. Also your recursive call is wrong, it should be `pushAtbottom(data, s);` instead of `pushAtbottom(4,s);`.

Answer (score 1):

`pushAtbottom` is a method of your class, not of `java.util.Stack`. You need to declare it as static (i.e., `static void ushAtbottom(int data,Stack<Integer> s)`) and then pass the stack to it when calling it form `main`:

```java
pushAtbottom(6, s);
```